# How to get 2 values from 2 differents RxJava Observables?

Tags: java-8, rx-java

I have 2 Observables that will return only 1 thing. I need both
   values to do something else.

How can I subscribe to both Observables and receive a notification
   only when both values are available?

I tried something like:

```java
   final Observable<String> obs1 = Observable.just("A", "B");
   final Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.just("A", "B");

   Observable.zip(
       obs1,
       obs2,
       (a, b) -> {
         System.out.println("Processing " + a + b);
         return null;
       }
   );
```

But nothing happens unless I register a subscriber (which would be
   useless).

The (ugly) solution I used is an embedded subscription such as:

```java
   final Observable<String> obs1 = Observable.just("A", "B");
   final Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.just("A", "B");

   obs1.subscribe(
     a -> {
       obs2.subscribe(
         b -> {
           System.out.println("Processing " + a + b);
         }
       );
     }
   );
```

What is the way to do such a common thing?

Comment: Zip is the way to go and you have to subscribe something, at least a Subscriber that logs errors to get it going. Btw, your example returns two things per Observable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observables are lazy so you need a subscriber to do the work. To combine items from both observables you need to use the `zip` operator. Just one small modification to your first solution:

```
final Observable<String> obs1 = Observable.just("A", "B");
   final Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.just("A", "B");

   Observable.zip(
       obs1,
       obs2,
       (a, b) -> {
         System.out.println("Processing " + a + b);
         return null;
       }
   ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Ok, I'm new to RX and I never used the #subscribe() method before. Now I know what its purpose is.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Time has passed and RxJava2 forbid passing nulls now :D

Comment: I would return a pair of `a` and `b` and print it in `subscribe`.... You can use Option or Notification to deal will nulls